# How to enable horizontal scrolling with keyboard keys?

Tags: css, scroll, keyboard, bulma

I bought Plexar theme on envato. It's an HTML theme based on Bulma, that I'm using for a personal project.
I have adapted it to my will and upload it here : http://journalbarre.com/tharwa/
But I would like to add the possibility to scroll on the page horizontally using the right and left keyboard keys. Here, the scrolling is possible with the mouse wheel but not with the keyboard. I would be very grateful if someone could provide me some help...
Thanks
yinans

Comment: Add tabindex="0" on the container that scrolls. This will allow keyboard navigation to focus on it. Then use the right and left arrow keys to move around inside the scrollable container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `swiper` so you should take a look here https://swiperjs.com/api/#keyboard maybe it will help you